# Como enviar un archivo a una api C#

Tags: c#, .net-core

Ya hice pruebas en postman y la api la consumo correctamente, con sus firmas y demás, pero no se como replicar esto en [image: Consumo de postman]

Comment: postman te da la opcion de generar el codigo, con la  funcion `Code snippet` , la opcion te aparece en la parte derecha del boton `Send` con un icono de esta manera `</>`

Comment: Si, pero no funciona o al menos no se como implementarlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El postman mismo sugiere esto y funciona

```
       Client.DownloadFile(request.Url, request.Name);
     
        var client = new RestClient(_host + _storageApi);
        client.Timeout = _httpTimeOut;
        var req = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        req.AddFile("file",{url de donde está el archivo});
        req.AddParameter("codigo_queja", request.CodigoQueja);
        req.AddParameter("type", request.TypeFile);
        var response = client.Execute(req);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SendStorageResponse>(response.Content);
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).